# Power BI measure how to determine which date range applies if there is overlap?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure as follows:

```
    Measure = 
VAR CurrentContractDate = SELECTEDVALUE( sales[Date] )

RETURN
    IF(
        NOT ISBLANK( CurrentContractDate ),
        CALCULATE( 
            SELECTEDVALUE( 'Employees'[Office Name] ), 
            FILTER( 'Employees', 'Employees'[Contract Start] <= CurrentContractDate && 'Employees'[Contract End] >= CurrentContractDate )
        )
    )
```

which takes the date found in my contracts table (sales[Date]) and determines whether that date fits between a date range in my employees table (Employees[Contract Start and Employees[Contract End]) and then will extract the corresponding city name (Employees[Office Name]).

The above works for situations where there only one contract for given sale date but returns empty results if multiple ranges are available or if the sale is made outside of an available date range for a given employee.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rank selected locations based on your criteria and select one with the highest/lowest (depending on rank direction) rank.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this

Comment: I keep trying to add an if statement to me measure but It doesn't like having more than one at a time. I keep getting errors about the structure.

Comment: It would be lots easier if you posted five rows of data with both the current results you get and the expected results of your ContractLocation measure. Reprex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a calculated table, which will be used to select the location that you want. I don't exactly understand what you mean by *"use the date range which has the least amount of days between them"*, so I will assume it's number of dates between start date and end date. If it's something else, you can always change the formula for calculating days.

This is just off the top of my head, I'm sure it can be optimised.

```
MyLocation = 
VAR CurrentContractDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE( Contracts[Date] )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ISBLANK ( CurrentContractDate ),
        VAR MyLocals =  //This gets all corresponding locations
            FILTER (
                Locals,
                Locals[Date Start] <= CurrentContractDate
                    && Locals[Date End] >= CurrentContractDate
            )
        VAR MyLocalsRanked = //This ranks the locations (in ascending order), based on 
            ADDCOLUMNS (     //number of days between start and end dates
                MyLocals,
                "Days", DATEDIFF ( [Date Start], [Date End], DAY ),
                "Rank", RANKX ( MyLocals, DATEDIFF ( [Date Start], [Date End], DAY ),, 1 )
            )
        VAR MyLocal =  //This selects the one with the highest rank
            TOPN ( 1, MyLocalsRanked, [Rank], 1 )
        RETURN
            SELECTCOLUMNS ( MyLocal, "Location", [Location] ) //This returns the name of the location
    )
```

As usual, when you look again, you see that there are some superfluous steps...

```
MyLocation = 
VAR CurrentContractDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE( Contracts[Date] )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ISBLANK ( CurrentContractDate ),
        VAR MyLocals =  //This gets all corresponding locations
            FILTER (
                Locals,
                Locals[Date Start] <= CurrentContractDate
                    && Locals[Date End] >= CurrentContractDate
            )

        VAR MyLocal =  //This selects the one with the lowest number of days
            TOPN ( 1, MyLocals, DATEDIFF ( [Date Start], [Date End], DAY ), 1 )
        RETURN
            SELECTCOLUMNS ( MyLocal, "Location", [Location] ) //This returns the name of the location
    )
```

**EDIT**

The modification to select contracts even when there is no matching date is fairly simple. The logic is basically the same - use ranking system to select best location. But first, you have to remove filtering based on dates and then you need to rank results and come up with a rank formula that will prefer matching locations and select non-matching as a last resort. For instance:

```
MyLocation =
VAR CurrentContractDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Contracts[Date] )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ISBLANK ( CurrentContractDate ),
        VAR MyLocal =
            TOPN (
                1,
                Locals,
                IF (
                    CurrentContractDate <= Locals[Date End]
                        && CurrentContractDate >= Locals[Date End], //Check, whether there is matching date
                    DATEDIFF ( Locals[Date Start], Locals[Date End], DAY ), //If so, rank matching locations (you may want to employ a different formula)
                    MIN (  //If the location is not matching, calculate how close it is (from both start and end date)
                        ABS ( DATEDIFF ( CurrentContractDate, Locals[Date Start], DAY ) ),
                        ABS ( DATEDIFF ( CurrentContractDate, Locals[Date End], DAY ) )
                    ) + 1000000 //Add a discriminating factor in case there are matching rows that should be favoured over non-matching.
                ), 1
            )
        RETURN
            FIRSTNONBLANK(SELECTCOLUMNS ( MyLocal, "Location", [City] ) )//This returns the name of the location. In case of tie on the top spot, it returns the first value.
    )
```

Comment: The issue here is that if the employee has only one contract, it isn't returning a result when it should. Only employees with multiple contracts is working.

Comment: That should not be the case. It's something else in your data that is causing it most likely, but I can't tell without data.

Comment: I've just checked with some random data and it does work. See here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmqvMyRqhrBpgtheivGedR90m9ABrg?e=ysNPjU.

This approach, with some minor modification could also be used to find the closest location, if no location is found for the contract date.

Comment: you're totally right. The issue I was having is in my edited question wherein the employee didn't have a contract detail available for the date of her sale. I'd like it if it could use the next best option (detailed in question) if available but if no contracts exist at all to then output "No Office"

Comment: You can download the sample again, it shows locations for contracts when date is not between start and end.

Comment: Hi, I did have a look, but your table is completely broken and the measure is completely different than what I have given above. I'm sorry, but I am not willing to troubleshoot that. I have given a solution that works.

Comment: That's embarassing, I uploaded the wrong version. If you look at it now you should see that the tables are working but adding the measure into the visualization breaks everything because of the error.

Comment: This is because you have a tie on the top spot and two or more rows are returned. You can either come up with a formula that will alleviate that or return first value with `FIRSTNONBLANK(SELECTCOLUMNS ( MyLocal, "Location", [OfficeID] ), [Location])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229216/discussion-between-sweepster-and-w-b).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
ContractLocation =
VAR CurrentContractDate = SELECTEDVALUE ( Contracts[Date] )
VAR ValidLocals =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            Locals,
            Locals[Date Start] <= CurrentContractDate
                && Locals[Date End] >= CurrentContractDate
        ),
        "@Length", Locals[Date End] - Locals[Date Start]
    )
VAR MinLength = MINX ( ValidLocals, [@Length] )
RETURN
    MAXX ( FILTER ( ValidLocals, [@Length] = MinLength ), [Location] )
```

This finds the minimal length contract and then returns the top location with that length.